# Name for special type of wheel graph

Tags: graph

Is there a name for this graph? It would be a wheel graph, except that alternate bounding edges have been removed (similar to the "radioactivity" warning symbol):

[special wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ39g.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add that the wheel blades can be any number, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: it's a windmill graph:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windmill_graph

According to that page, it is actually a special type of windmill known as a "friendship graph".